# Add fields of a table to the parent table in serializers

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I have three tables users,posts and comments.
The serializer of post is

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :content, :like, :created_at, :updated_at
attributes :user
has_many :comments
def user
    object.user
end
end
```

Comments have the following attributes.The comment serializer is

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :comment, :created_at, :updated_at
attributes :user
attributes :post
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
def user
  object.user
end
def post
  object.post
end
end
```

I need the attributes of comments when I print the JSON of posts.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the `serializer` option in your `has_many` association in `PostSerializer`

Change

`has_many :comments`

To

`has_many :comments, serializer: CommentSerializer`

Hope this helps